# Implementing the board to act as a UVC device

Tags: uvc

all,

I wanted to do a capture and encoding of camera modules, and made in the form uvc device, now I have a development board can capture and encoding, If I implementing the board to act as a UVC device, when used otg or usb connection the development board, you can see the image acquisition.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].